# c# crc8 bit to lua function

Tags: c#, lua, crc

Hi Ive searched the web and here and think the only solution is to ask someone familiar with both LUA and C#...

I have a CRC 8bit code snippet which essentially I need in Lua...
Im new to Lua but have managed to write some code to solve a problem, but there is a new version out which requires a 8bit CRC check on EVERY message...

I had to google what CRC checks were and how they were done and I THINK I have grasped the concept... I am completely clueless as to how to script this in Lua... I have found a snippet of c# code saying it is a simple general 8 bit crc calculation and I think if this were in Lua I would be able to adapt it suitably but there appears to be no direct conversion facilities anywhere on the web...

I noticed you guys have helped out similar problems before and hope you can assist me now... I had to sign a nondisclosure agreement to read it hence not posting the code and being slightly cagey about details... But if I post this non specific general 8bit CRC calculation routine maybe someone could convert it for me or write a similar script in Lua? For my purposes I would only need to "decode" a hexadecimal byte string (pretty sure Ive just made that up!) and tell the receiver what the result of the CRC check should be...

so i have a string of hex like:
3F 12 34 22 22 09 (completely made up and nonsensical for example)

which I need to add an 8 bi CRC check result to (hopefully that makes sense!)
following is the general 8bit check C# code I've found:

```
private byte calcCRC8(ref byte[] data, int bytes)
{ 
    byte crc = 0xff;
    byte poly = 0x85;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) 
    { 
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        { 
            if ((crc & 0x80) == 0x80)
            { 
                crc = (byte)((crc << 1) ^ poly);
            }
            else
            { 
                crc = (byte)(crc << 1);
            } 
        }              
    }
    return crc; 
}
```

ANY assistance would be GREATLY appreciated,

Sam

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html

Comment: Do you know your polynom?  Do you have examples of data with its correct CRC value?  What would be the correct CRC for `3F 12 34 22 22 09`?

Comment: This i s not a code translation service. Either learn Lua or pay someone who did.

Comment: Also, this code looks like it was translated from C by someone who barely knows C#.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who far, I'll ignore piglets comment however as I'm sure when he reads posts properly in a non cynical mood he is very helpful. I explicitly stated that I was planning lua and would try and adapt any answers therefore fairly obvious i felt that I was trying to learn... I'm not ashamed to be stuck on something and definitely not ashamed to ask for help from a community with so many talented developers (especially on a website designed for people to ask questions!)

Comment: *who has helped so far, *stated that I was learning lua

Comment: Piglet is essentially correct. _"But if I post this non specific general 8bit CRC calculation routine maybe someone could convert it for me or write a similar script in Lua?"_ is in fact an inappropriate request on stackoverflow. What you would be expected to do is to sincerely attempt the conversion yourself, and then if you can't get it to work, post the attempt here, what problems you encountered, and ask for help with that.

Comment: Ok apologies to all - I thought I was clearer, I meant that if someone could do that it would help me to understand the processes and how to write my own script. As you can see from the number of edits I make I am prone to mistakes when posting during work time due to time pressures (my job is not coding related at all so shouldn't really be on here at all during work hours lol)

Answer (score 1):

Whoever is requiring an 8-bit CRC must be requiring a *specific* 8-bit CRC. Step one before worrying about the language is to make sure you know how to to calculate the correct CRC. Does the documentation provide the CRC parameters, such as the polynomial, bit-ordering, initial value, final xor? Does the documentation provide an example message and the corresponding CRC?

Comment: It doesn't specifically state as much although I am able to contact the developers of the protocol and ask them... In the example I'm guessing the line "byte poly" is the polynomial (which I didn't fully grasp what a polynomial is btw :s) not sure what the line "byte crc" is? Maybe initial value? Sadly there is no "working example" as it were... Thanks for your help so far I'll contact the developers (who are not particularly code savvy I feel... No offence to them! ) for the bits of info needed

Comment: @SamYoué - Just ask the developers what would be the correct CRC for string "HELLO".  It would be enough to deduce the polynom and other parameters of the algorithm.

Comment: Will do thank you, I'll get back to you guys with the result